# How to connect Jupyter Ipython notebook to Amazon redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am using Mac Yosemite.
I have installed the packages postgresql, psycopg2, and simplejson using conda install "package name".
After the installation I have imported these packages. I tried to create a json file with my amazon redshift credentials

```
{
    "user_name": "YOUR USER NAME",
    "password": "YOUR PASSWORD",
    "host_name": "YOUR HOST NAME",
    "port_num": "5439",
    "db_name": "YOUR DATABASE NAME"
}
```

I used with

```
open("Credentials.json") as fh:
    creds = simplejson.loads(fh.read())
```

But this is throwing error. These were the instructions given on a website. I tried searching other websites but no site gives a good explanation.

Please let me know the ways I can connect the Jupyter to amazon redshift.

Comment: Did you open the security group on the cluster to allow connection from your IP address?

Comment: *What* error does it give you?

Comment: For anybody getting certificate errors, use this connection argument: `engine = sa.create_engine('redshift+redshift_connector://user:passwordv@host:port/db',connect_args={'sslmode': "allow"})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

```
----INSERT IN CELL 1-----
import psycopg2
redshift_endpoint = "<add your endpoint>"
redshift_user = "<add your user>"
redshift_pass = "<add your password>"
port = <your port>
dbname = "<your db name>"

----INSERT IN CELL 2-----
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import text
engine_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s" \
% (redshift_user, redshift_pass, redshift_endpoint, port, dbname)
engine = create_engine(engine_string)

----INSERT IN CELL 3 - THIS EXAMPLE WILL GET ALL TABLES FROM YOUR DATABASE-----
sql = """
select schemaname, tablename from pg_tables order by schemaname, tablename;
"""

----LOAD RESULTS AS TUPLES TO A LIST-----
tables = []
output = engine.execute(sql)
for row in output:
    tables.append(row)
tables

--IF YOU'RE USING PANDAS---
raw_data = pd.read_sql_query(text(sql), engine)
```

Comment: The other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48792314/1335793 hides the credentials in a separate file which is _much_ better than storing them in plain text.

Answer (score 7):

There's a nice guide from RJMetrics here: ["Setting up Your Analytics Stack with Jupyter Notebook & AWS Redshift"](https://blog.rjmetrics.com/2016/02/08/setting-up-your-analytics-stack-with-jupyter-notebook-aws-redshift/). It uses [`ipython-sql`](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql)

This works great and displays results in a grid.

In [1]:

```
import sqlalchemy
import psycopg2
import simplejson
%load_ext sql
%config SqlMagic.displaylimit = 10
```

In [2]:

```
with open("./my_db.creds") as fh:
    creds = simplejson.loads(fh.read())

connect_to_db = 'postgresql+psycopg2://' + \
                creds['user_name'] + ':' + creds['password'] + '@' + \
                creds['host_name'] + ':' + creds['port_num'] + '/' + creds['db_name'];
%sql $connect_to_db
```

In [3]:

```
% sql SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 25;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use this extension - 
https://github.com/sat28/jupyter-redshift

The sample notebook shows how it loads redshift utility as an IPython Magic.

**Edit 1**

Support for writing back to redshift database has also been added.